# Backdooring Generic Lists through IList

Tags: c#, generics, ilist

I have a scenario where a class loads objects of one type, due do abstractions I can not use a generic class  (generics tend to spread like cancer :) but I often want to work with a generic version of the objects once retrieved, which resulted in code like this (simplified):

```
List<SomeClass> items = Storage.LoadItems(filename).OfType<SomeClass>().ToList();
```

Where LoadItems returns a List<object>, then I realized, why not instead have

```
public void LoadItems(string filename,IList list);
```

Now I can do this instead

```
List<SomeClass> items = new  List<SomeClass>();
LoadItems(filename,items);
```

Which should be more efficient. It's also seems a bit more flexible since I can take an existing List and tack on new items. So my questions are, is this a common pattern or do you have a different/better way of achieving this?

I'm also a bit curious that you can do this, if you try and add a object of the wrong type you get an exception, but does that mean that generic lists also do a type check? (which seems a bit unecessary)

**EDIT**
It might actually be a bit more elegant to modify the pattern to

```
public IList LoadItems(string filename,IList list=null);
```

that way you can use the statement fluently and if no list is passed you could simply instantiate a List<object>

Comment: "if you try and add a object of the wrong type you get an exception, but does that mean that generic lists also do a type check?"

Of course they do.  Generics are strongly typed.  Why would it be unnecessary that generics check type before loading?

Comment: May I ask why abstraction should render generics unusable? Generics and abstraction should rather support each other. You can use a placeholder for the generic type like List<T> where necessary.

Comment: In some scenarios where you have lot's of factories, interfaces etc using generic versions of (your own) classes make things very hard or impossible since you upfront don't know your T, and it also requires lot's of other classes to be generic. I think Marc also can attest to the potential problems of injecting generics into your class structure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List<T>` implements `IList` explicitly. 
The implementations cast to `T` and call the regular (generic) methods.

Thus, type-checking only happens if you explicitly call the `IList` methods.
For example:

```
void System.Collections.IList.Insert(int index, Object item) 
{
    ThrowHelper.IfNullAndNullsAreIllegalThenThrow<T>(item, ExceptionArgument.item); 

    try {
        Insert(index, (T) item); 
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException) {
        ThrowHelper.ThrowWrongValueTypeArgumentException(item, typeof(T));
    } 
}
```

It doesn't use the `as` keyword because the `T` might be a value type.
You can only write `as T` if you wrote `where T : class`.

Comment: ah, that makes sense,  although using "as" and an if-statement rather than boxing and try-catch in your example would probable be more performant

Comment: @MattiasK: I'm well aware of that.  However, it wouldn't compile. You can only use the `as` keyword on a generic parameter if you constrain it with `where T : class`.  Lists can contain structs.

Answer (score 1):

Using `IList` is fine in most cases; and is **certainly** faster than using reflection or `dynamic` to achieve the same.

Yes it will add a type-check (by virtue of the cast/unbox), but that will not be onerous. If `T` is a `struct` then you also have some boxing/unboxing, but that too isn't as bad as people fear.

In that scenario, `IList` would be fine by me.

Answer (score 0):

**Your solution does look sound, there is nothing wrong with it.**

Concerning the `Add`, it doesn't really do a type check. The code for the `Add` you refer to is this:

```
int System.Collections.IList.Add(Object item)
{
    try {
        Add((T) item);
    }
    catch (InvalidCastException) {
        throw ...;
    }

    return Count - 1;
}
```

It doesn't do a type check; it's just a try/catch.

Comment: The `(T)item` is implicitly a type-check *of sorts*.

Comment: Yes and no. Of course it checks the type, but there is no check here. It's more like lets see how far we'll get. If the catch would convert it to something like -1 (result instead of exception), this would probably make me cry. With "check" I mean something that involves an `if` :).

Answer (score 0):

I like the second approach.

You can pass the IList but then check the type to see if it is a generic list and if so, get generic type and load only records of that type:

```
   Type itemType = typeof (object);
   if(list.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Length>0)
   {
       itemType = list.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];
   }

   for (int i = 0; i < recordCount; i++)
   {
      if(record.GetType().IsInstanceOfType(itemType))
   }
```